# Wamp Server and PHP mailer

Tags: phpmailer, wampserver

I have a WAMP server database which contains users with their emails and activation codes.
How do I send an email for every new record in the WAMP server database automatically with its activation code? Using PHP.
P.s: I can already send an email from WAMP using PHP mailer but I have to specify the receiver each time.

This is the mail.php script that I use for sending emails using PHP mailer

```
<?php
   require "init.php";
   require"PHPMailerAutoload.php";
   require 'class.phpmailer.php';

   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';   
   $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
   $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   $mail->Port = "587"; 
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
   $mail->Username = "******@gmail.com";
   $mail->Password = "******";

   $mail->From     = "*******@gmail.com";
   $mail->FromName = "Vodafone-El7a2ny";
   $mail->AddAddress("*****", "Marwa Hashem");

   $mail->Subject  = "Activation Code";
   $mail->Body     = " Dear User,


                    Thank you for registering in El72any Mobile Application,

                  Your Activation Code is 


Best Regards,
****";

   $mail->WordWrap = 50;  

   if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Email was not sent.';
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
   } else {
        echo 'Email has been sent.';
   }
?>
```

This is the register.php script

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$EmailAddress=$_POST["EmailAddress"];
$MobileNumber=$_POST["MobileNumber"];
$Password=$_POST["Password"];

$sql_query = "insert into user_information VALUES('$EmailAddress', '$MobileNumber', '$Password','');";



if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
{
echo "<h3>Database Insertion Success...</h3>";
}

else
{
echo "Data Inerstion Error...".mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

Also this is the init.php script I used to connect to my database

```
<?php
$db_name="CustomerDB";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass=null;
$server_name="localhost";


$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);

if(!$con)
{
echo "Connection Error...".mysqli_connect_error();


}

else
{
echo "<h3>Database connection Success...</h3>";

}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really an opinion question since you've not posted any code. It helps to start by reading the docs and examples that are provided with PHPMailer. In your case, start with [the mailing list example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Comment: I added both the codes for the registration and the mail php scripts 
what I want is that whenever a new record is inserted int the database after the user registers, a confirmation mail to be sent automatically to that user with the body containing the user's activation code (which is a primary key in the table and auto incremented in the WAMP server database) , so how do I retrieve both?

Comment: thank you so much the mailing list example helped me a lot !